# Telethon бесконечный вход

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, telethon

Пытаюсь совместить использование aiogram и Telethon в одном проекте. Однако столкнулся с проблемой бесконечного ожидания ответа от клиента.
Код для репродукции ошибки:

```py
class ChatJoiner:
  def __init__(self, client=None):
    self.client = client or telethon_client or telethon.TelegramClient(api_hash=config.api_hash, 
                                                                  api_id=config.api_id,
                                                                  session="telegram.session") 
  def join_chat(self, chat_name):
            log.info(f"Joining chat {chat}")
            async with self._client as client:
              updates = await client(JoinChannelRequest(chat))
              log.debug(f"Joined {updates}")
              return updates.chats[0]
```

И файл с ботом

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=Menu.adding_chat)
    log.debug("Handled new_chat_add_success_handler")
    try:
        chat = await message_listener.join_chat(message.text)
    except Exception as e:
        log.warning(f"Smth ({e}) occurred while getting access to group {message.text}")
        await send_message(message.from_id, texts.Messages.smth_wrong + " " + str(e), bot)
        return
```

Про срабатывании хэндлера на присоединение к чату блок внутри with выполняется бесконечно долго. В режиме отладки Telethon-а:

```
DEBUG:bot:Handled new_chat_add_success_handler
INFO:telethon_:Joining chat https://t.me/test_group_face
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 91.108.56.169:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
DEBUG:aiogram:Make request: "getUpdates" with data: "{'offset': 790161811, 'timeout': 20}" and files "None"
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting send loop
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Starting receive loop
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 91.108.56.169:443/TcpFull complete!
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 7139477016135257356 to InvokeWithLayerRequest (1cd167bb370)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 76 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling bad salt for message 7139477016135257356
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:1 message(s) will be resent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
```

Причем если импортировать файл с классом например из ipython-а то код выполняется спокойно.